# Angular 8 Deployment - Single-Page-Application Trouble After Updating Ubuntu

Tags: angular, deployment, routes, ubuntu-20.04

Here's where I'm at after googling for a few days:

After updating ubuntu from 16.04 to 20.04, my application's routes no longer work properly. Going directly to url.com/web gets me to a "Cannot GET /web" screen.  Locally, going to url.com/web works fine.

This leads me to this:  Ubuntu no longer knows how to deal with the SPA after the update, and I need to set it up to reach index.html, using Path Location Strategy. And so, I've read, that I need to add this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html
```

I've done that, but it introduces another problem.  And I don't know if I'm adding it in the right way or  right spot.  I'm a boot camp grad and we didn't cover deployment much at all, but the following code was added to nginx.  Here's where I added the try_files code:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```

This might have fixed this one problem, but it causes my  not to load anything.  My basic index.html template loads, but doesn't populate the app-root. It's only a white screen.

I tried a number of variations, but I'm not experienced enough in this code to understand where my problem lies.  (Not to mention I don't really know what much of this deployment code actually does.)

Here's more information that I think is relevant:

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

app.listen(8000, () => console.log("listening on port 8000"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/public/dist/public' ));

app.all("*", (req,res,next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("./public/dist/public/index.html"))
});
```

In app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '',component: ShellPortfolioComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '',component: ProjectsComponent },
        ]
     },
    { path: 'web',component: ShellPortfolioWebComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '',component: WebProjectsComponent },
        ]
    },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Angular 8.3.20
Ubuntu 20.04

And again, all of this worked fine before I updated ubuntu, and it works fine locally.

So, what am I missing?  Thank you!

Comment: What is the reason for the node-js express server? Why don't you serve your static files directly with nginx? `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` wont work since nginx is not the one serving the files. If you want try_files to work, then get rid of the proxy_pass and let nginx serve those static files.

Comment: Your current nginx config says: There is some webserver which listens on http://locahost:80/ and proxies all requests to your nodejs-express server on http://localhost:8080. Is the nodejs express server running? Do you want to keep that proxy setup? You could also look at the nginx logs and see if you find something there, the logs can be found at /var/log/nginx/

Comment: I'm using express only because it was part of the tech stack that was taught(MEAN).  However, your comments led to me getting it working.  I didn't have express installed on the ubuntu server.  I'm not sure why it worked before, but alas...If you submit an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I am all good. Good luck on your journey!